# Esri request: do not retrieve geometry

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, esri-geodatabase

I need to make an esriRequest without filtering the results, like this:

```
require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/request"
], function(esriConfig, esriRequest) {
    esriConfig.request.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
    esriRequest(
        'http://.../MapServer/0/query', 
        {
            query: { 
                f: "json",
                where: "(1=1)",
                outFields: '*'
            },
            responseType: 'json'
        }
    ).then(function(response) {

    });
});
```

My problem is that `features.geometry` data is really big, and it takes several seconds before end-users see the result.
Is there a way to only receive `feature.attributes` data?

Comment: have you tried: returnGeometry: false ?

Comment: Many thanks, this is the kind of option I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
returnGeometry: false
```

is an option for the REST request

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Query_Map_Service_Layer/02r3000000p1000000/